# Yarn force a package to use a specific version

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I currently have the the following issue when running a unit test using the Jest Vue cli plugin found here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest

Error I receive is `Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that somet
hing in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@
babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel`

I am using Yarn workspaces and would like to know the best way to force `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest` to use babel-core of version `^7.0.0-0`